# form doesn't appears in custom template page

Tags: forms, wordpress

I am newer to wordpress.i have created a form using form builder.and included in a page.The form displays in the default template but not in the custom template.any idea??

Comment: may i know your theme name ? twentyten or ...

Comment: ya..i created a custom template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Formbuilder manual form display. Replace the # in the following line with the ID number of the form to be displayed.
if(function_exists('formbuilder_process_form')) echo formbuilder_process_form(#);
// End of FormBuilder manual form display.
```